# Google Analytics API (per day pageviews)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Analytics API within my Node application, and have the following so far:

`const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
  'auth': jwt,
  'ids': 'ga:' + viewId,
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'today',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
});`

Returns:

`...
rows: [ [ '168' ] ] }`

This works great so far! But, instead of grabbing the total number of pageviews, I'm looking to have the data returned so I can see hits per day as I'd like to create a graph within my application to show this off using a chart library. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will do it!

`const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
  'auth': jwt,
  'ids': 'ga:' + viewId,
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'today',
  'dimensions': 'ga:date',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
});`

Produces:

````

```
rows: [ [ '20181102', '0' ],
 [ '20181103', '2' ],
 [ '20181104', '0' ],
 [ '20181105', '0' ],
 [ '20181106', '2' ],
 [ '20181107', '12' ],
 [ '20181108', '10' ],
 [ '20181109', '11' ],
 [ '20181110', '7' ],
 [ '20181111', '20' ],
 [ '20181112', '6' ],
 [ '20181113', '16' ],
 [ '20181114', '8' ],
 [ '20181115', '8' ],
 [ '20181116', '4' ],
 [ '20181117', '9' ],
 [ '20181118', '2' ],
 [ '20181119', '2' ],
 [ '20181120', '7' ],
 [ '20181121', '4' ],
 [ '20181122', '3' ],
 [ '20181123', '3' ],
 [ '20181124', '4' ],
 [ '20181125', '0' ],
 [ '20181126', '3' ],
 [ '20181127', '6' ],
 [ '20181128', '2' ],
 [ '20181129', '3' ],
 [ '20181130', '0' ],
 [ '20181201', '6' ],
 [ '20181202', '9' ] ]
```